# SQL update not updating anything

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, express

I'm trying to update a value in a table when a certain condition is met however nothing is updating:

```
    if (req.headers['user-agent'].includes('HeadlessChrome') && (end - start <= 500))  {
        db.run("UPDATE tab SET var = '1234' WHERE var = '5678'",  (err) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err.message); 
            }
        })
    }
    var query = "SELECT * FROM tab"
    db.all(query, (error, rows) => {
        ...
```

The db.all(query..) seems to just return the value before the UPDATE, which makes me think UPDATE isn't working as it should. I've verified that the IF statement is entered. Any ideas?

Comment: try running find query in update callback, db operations are asynchronous

Comment: How would I do that? I'm unsure how callbacks work.

Comment: Which database are you using?  Oracle, for example, requires a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` to persist any changes.  Have you validated that the table `tab` actually contains rows with `var = '5678'`?  Have you tried it directly on the database's command line or some other environment outside of your application?

Comment: Yeah, I call a db.all(query) that SELECTs every value from that table and prints it out and 5678 is there. I'm using sqlite3.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is dummy data - the real data is something like test{1234_5678} and I'm wanting to replace it with test{5678_1234}.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.run("UPDATE tab SET var = '1234' WHERE var = '5678'",  (err) => {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err.message); 
        }
        var query = "SELECT * FROM tab"
        db.all(query, (error, rows) => { console.log(rows) }
    })
```

Calling `db.all(query, (error, rows)` in update callback makes sure you are querying an updated value